# Manipulating components in a separate class java

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have three java classes

**StitchSorts**

```
import Sorts.*;

public class StitchSorts
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StitchSorts sS = new StitchSorts();
        SortsGui.main(args);
    }
}
```

**SortsGui**

```
package Sorts;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import Sorts.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SortsGui
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Sorts");

    JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();

    MyMenuBar mbr = new MyMenuBar();

    JTextField txtField = new JTextField();
    JTextField txtField2 = new JTextField();

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 800, 800);
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createSortTestPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(sortPanel);

        myMainWindow.setJMenuBar(mbr);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createSortTestPanel()
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("" , "[grow]");
        sortPanel.setLayout(layout);

        sortPanel.add(txtField,"growx");
        sortPanel.add(txtField2,"growx");
    }

    public void clearTextBoxes()
    {
        for (Component C : sortPanel.getComponents())
        {    
            if (C instanceof JTextField)
            {
                ((JTextField) C).setText("");
                System.out.println("Multiple");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SortsGui sG = new SortsGui();
        sG.runGUI();
    }
}
```

**MyMenuBar**

```
package Sorts;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar
{
    JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
    SortsGui sG;

    public MyMenuBar()
    {
        setBorderPainted(true);
        makePopUpMenu();
    }

    void makePopUpMenu()
    {
        add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        clearButton(btnClear);
        add(btnClear);
    }

    public void clearButton(JButton J)
    {
        J.setOpaque(false); //These remove the button filling and border
        J.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        J.setBorder(null);
        J.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50,25));
        J.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,25));
        J.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50,25));
        J.addActionListener(new buttonPress());
        J.setFocusable(false);
    }

    class buttonPress implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {               
            if(e.getSource() == btnClear)
            {
                System.out.println("Clearing");
                sG = new SortsGui();
                sG.clearTextBoxes();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is when the JButton `btnClear` is clicked the JTextFields in `SortsGui` should be cleared. The public void `clearTextBoxes` I set up to achieve this works when it is called in `SortsGui`. However when the method is called by the `btnClear` being clicked, it does not detect any JTextFields on the JPanel `sortPanel`. Is there a way to correct this? If so what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your code is kinda nuts.  It doesn't make sense to me to sub-class a JMenuBar.  You should provide functionality in ActionListeners attached to the menus.  But on your question: what does "detect any JTextFields" mean?  Where do you have the problem in code?  What method name and line number?

Comment: from the code you have uploaded it is evident that the instance of `SortsGui` that is being displayed and the instance `SortsGui` used in `btnClear` action are different instances. So you code does not work.

Comment: @Blip How would you do it so that they are in the same instance?

Comment: He means you are calling "new SortGui()" twice (or more).  Only call it once, and use only that reference.

Comment: Why do you have a reference to "StitchSorts"? It isn't referenced anywhere else in your code.

Comment: @bakoyaro just to make sure that it wasn't effecting my program in a way I was unaware of which would cause this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the code here:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {               
        if(e.getSource() == btnClear)
        {
            System.out.println("Clearing");
            sG = new SortsGui(); // You are creating a new instance of SortsGui
            sG.clearTextBoxes(); //You are calling the method on this new instance
        }
    }
```

The solution to your problem could be done by passing the instance of the `SortsGui` in the constructor of the `MyMenuBar` and storing it in an instance variable say `sG` as you have done in your code like below:

```
public MyMenuBar(SortsGui sG)
{
    this.sG = sG;
    setBorderPainted(true);
    makePopUpMenu();
}
```

Now in the action performed method remove the line:

```
  sG = new SortsGui();
```

Now in the initialisation of the variable `mbr` in `SortsGui` class use the following code:

```
MyMenuBar mbr = new MyMenuBar(this);
```

instead of

```
MyMenuBar mbr = new MyMenuBar();
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This produces the error Sorts\SortsGui.java:16: error: constructor MyMenuBar in class MyMenuBar cannot be applied to given types;
        MyMenuBar mbr = new MyMenuBar(this);
        
  required: no arguments
  found: SortsGui
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Did you first change and compile `MyMenuBar.java`?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. The code works fine. Thank you for helping